# Invalid use of non-static member function using vector.sort()

Tags: c++

I want to sort a two-dimensional vector based on its first column using the sort() function but unfortunately, I get an "invalid use of non-static member function compareAscending" error by passing "compareAscending" function.

I have also tried to make the function static but got the same problem.

```
static bool compareAscending(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2) 
{ 
    return (v1[0] < v2[0]); 
}
```

This is comparator which I wanna use for the sort function

```
bool compareAscending(const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2) 
{ 
    return (v1[0] < v2[0]); 
}
```

And this is the sort function which I wanna call

```
sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), compareAscending);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: What is `vect`?

Comment: Needs a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: *tried to make the function static but got the same problem*: You got the _same_ error message for a `static` function? That seems unlikely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> invalid use of non-static member function compareAscending

Make the sorting function a non class member or make it `static` - or use a lambda:

```
std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(),
    [](const std::vector<int>& v1, const std::vector<int>& v2) {
        return v1[0] < v2[0];
    }
);
```

A `static` version:

```
class foo {
public:
    static bool compareAscending(const std::vector<int>& v1,
                                 const std::vector<int>& v2) {
        return v1[0] < v2[0];
    }
};

std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), foo::compareAscending);
```

A free function version:

```
bool compareAscending(const std::vector<int>& v1,
                      const std::vector<int>& v2) {
    return v1[0] < v2[0];
}

std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), compareAscending);
```

Comment: Well, according to OP he tried the second one and got the *"the same problem"*.

Comment: @uneven_mark :-) yeah, I took that with a grain of salt.