# invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool node::ncompare(node*, node*)’ when sorting a std::vector

Tags: c++

I have been trying to sort vector nodelist of type node (class declared for singly linked list).

```
bool ncompare(node* p, node* pnext)
   {return (p->data > pnext->data);}
void sort()
   {sort(nodelist.begin(),nodelist.end(),ncompare);}
```

However its showing the following error:

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void node::sort()’:

main.cpp:166:47: error: invalid use of non-static member function ‘bool node::ncompare(node*, node*)’
  sort(nodelist.begin(),nodelist.end(),ncompare);}

main.cpp:162:6: note: declared here
 bool ncompare(node* p, node* pnext)
```

I have declared these functions as a member of class node so there is no problem with accessing its elements.

Comment: Make `ncompare` static: `static bool ncompare(node* p, node* pnext)` - that's what the compiler is telling you to do

Comment: I dumped part of your error message into StackOverflow and found this question: [Invalid use of non-static member function using vector.sort()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58189633/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-using-vector-sort) Please do a cursory search before you post.

Comment: `ncompair` has 3 parameters, because of the implicit `this` pointer to your object, and not 2 as you need for your compair functor. By using static, you remove the reference to your class and it should work.

Comment: If you intent to use sort in [algorithm.h](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), try `std::sort(nodelist.begin(), ....)`. they has conflict on same name when you call it without namespace 'std'